# InAppBrowser not being called in Phonegap 3.1.0

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I've grabbed the latest version of phonegap from NPM and installed it.  I created a new project and added the InAppBrowser plugin per the docs on the PhoneGap .  I then make a JavaScript call from my webapp but I never see the alert I have coded below nor do I see it with any breakpoints I have setup in Xcode for the plugin.

Here's the code for the JS:

```
var pdfViewer = {
    loadPdf: function(record, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var filename = record.get('building') + "-" + record.get('floor') + ".pdf";
        var url = People.app.srvcUrl + Global.floorPlanUri + filename + "?access_token=" + People.app.bearerToken.access_token;
        if (Ext.os.is.iOS) {
        //    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PDFViewer", "loadRemotePdf", [url, filename]);


            var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert("You made it!"); });
        } else {
            window.open(url, '_system', 'location=yes');
        }
    }
};
```

What happens is that the url is launched to show a PDF on top of my existing app with no alert and no location/close button.  Any ideas why InAppBrowser is not being used?  I need to have it show in a window with a close button.

Here's the output I see in Xcode when I run the app:

```
2013-10-23 09:39:02.380 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-10-23 09:39:02.426 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2013-10-23 09:39:02.564 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] [CDVTimer][phonedialer] 0.477016ms
2013-10-23 09:39:02.567 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] [CDVTimer][sms] 0.230014ms
2013-10-23 09:39:02.569 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] [CDVTimer][emailcomposer] 0.252008ms
2013-10-23 09:39:02.571 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 7.416010ms
2013-10-23 09:39:02.957 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-10-23 09:39:05.789 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/5916FB20-FDEC-40A7-AE77-9EF14AF30585/mobile-xxx-ios.app/www/index.html
2013-10-23 09:39:18.168 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-10-23 09:39:18.680 mobile-xxx-ios[3302:60b] Finished load of: https://pdfs.xxx.com/noauth/plans/x-1.pdf
FAILED to create agar for HelveticaLTMM.
FAILED to create agar for TimesLTMM.
```

Here's my config.xml:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>Mobile App</name>

    <description>
        Mobile Phonegap Application
    </description>

    <access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <!-- Preferences for iOS -->
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />

    <feature name="SSLSelfCertOverride">
        <param name="ios-package" value="SSLSelfCertOverride" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="PhoneDialer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PhoneDialer"/>
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Sms">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Sms"/>
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="EmailComposer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="EmailComposer"/>
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PackageInfo">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PackageInfo" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="PDFViewer">
        <param name="ios-package" value="PDFViewer" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you added the server to the [whitelist](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide)? There's no log information at all from xcode?

Comment: Yes it's whitelisted and allows subdomains for *.  Xcode doesn't provide much information then what I already know. It does seem to confirm that InAppBrowser isn't being initialized by CDVTimer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by using the Cordova CLI commands exclusively to create the project and then to add the plugins.  It seems you have to use their build commands to get everything moved into the right directories.  Now I just issue a `cordova build` and that will build for iOS and Android with the appropriate plugin files in the correct spot.

I've also modified the generated js/index.js to call my Sencha Touch app as follows:

```
var device = false;
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        try {
            device = true;
            People.app.mainLaunch();
        }
        catch(e) {
            alert("Error: " + e);
        }

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

And then in my Sencha Touch app, I create I modified my launch method to prevent a race condition between my ST app being initialized before PhoneGap starting up as follows:

```
launch: function() {
    this.launched = true;
    this.mainLaunch();
},
mainLaunch: function() {
    try {
        if (this.launched && device) {
            Ext.Viewport.add({xtype:'myApp');
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Please check the followings:

**STEP 1**

In your "platforms/ios/www/plugins/", is there a "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" dir? 
If the answer is no, it's not successfully added.

**Solution**: Create dir "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/", and put "InAppBrowser.js" in it. You can find it in your PhoneGap project root "*yourproject*/plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/". Then go to step 2.

**STEP 2**

Open "platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js". In "module.exports", add:

```
    {
        "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser/www/InAppBrowser.js",
        "id": "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.InAppBrowser",
        "clobbers": [
            "window.open"
        ]
    }
```

In "module.exports.metadata", add:

```
    "org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser": "0.2.5"
```

and Save. "0.2.5" is the version of plugin, can be found in plugin.xml. (Looks like this number does not matter.)

Then run it, open your inspector and check if "InAppBrowser.js" is successfully added into the head tag.

**Note:** manually adding "InAppBrowser.js" into head tag without modifying "cordova_plugins.js" will not work. If answer to 1 is yes, go to step 2 directly.

Hopefully this solves your problem.

Comment: You're a magician. I've looked at 1000's of threads with the same problem and nobody knows what to do. I'll link to you from every post on this topic from now on.

Comment: Didn't work for me :( In Xcode 5 everything worked perfectly, but not in Xcode 6 (beta 7) The plugin's values are set in the config.xml, the javascript file is loaded. And if I call "window.open" InAppBrowser adds logs, but nothing is happening on screen!

Answer (score 0):

Check that your config.xml has these things:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.helloworld" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon gap:platform="webos" src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
    <icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="ldpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="mdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="hdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:density="xhdpi" gap:platform="android" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
    <gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" version="0.2.3" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.1.0" />
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <content src="index.html" />
</widget>
```

Comment: It's a little confusing what PG is doing here. If you create an app from the PG CLI and add the plugin you end up with 2 config.xml's (one in the root and one in the www directory). The one you show above is closest to the one in the www dir, but it does not add the plugin line you have.  Looking over their docs, it shows to add it in the root config.xml: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html.  At any rate, either approach doesn't work.  Does it for you?

Comment: No, sorry I haven't tested with iOS yet.  But to clarify, my config.xml comes from the non platform-specific www and the <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" version="0.1.0" /> code is used to tell the Phonegap Build service which plugins to add.

Comment: Please use the latest version which is 3.4 and it works fine.