# InAppBrowser not showing toolbar on ios6 with cordova 3.3.0

Tags: ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I work with Xcode 5, Cordova 3.3.0. The plugins has been installed by command line (cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser).

I tested on Ipad2 with ios6 and on simulator with ios7.

I don't have any problem to open html file or pdf file but I don't have ToolBar/Location Bar or other.

It's impossible to close pdf to return on previous page !!!

What can I check again? What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for your help ;-)

Content of my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>InAppBrowser.removeEventListener Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Global InAppBrowser reference
        var iabRef = null;

        function iabLoadStart(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }

        function iabLoadStop(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
        }

        function iabLoadError(event) {
            alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
        }

        function iabClose(event) {
            alert(event.type);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
            iabRef.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {

        }

        function openPdf() {
            iabRef = window.open('test.pdf', '_blank', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes,transitionstyle=fliphorizontal');
            iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
            iabRef.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
            iabRef.addEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
            iabRef.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
        }

        function openHtml() {
            // open win and turn off location
            var ref = window.open('index2.html', '_blank', 'location=no');

            // attach listener to loadstart
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
                var urlSuccessPage = "index2.html";
                if (event.url == urlSuccessPage) {
                    ref.close();
                }
            });
        }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <p><a href="javascript:openPdf();">PDF</a></p>
        <p><a href="javascript:openHtml();">page 2</a></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Content of my config file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.antidot.testpdf2" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
    <preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
    <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="GapBetweenPages" value="0" />
    <preference name="PageLength" value="0" />
    <preference name="PaginationBreakingMode" value="page" />
    <preference name="PaginationMode" value="unpaginated" />
    <feature name="LocalStorage">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage" />
    </feature>
    <name>test-pdf-2</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Console">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Comment: Any ideas for InAppBrowser problem?

Answer (score 0):

most likely the inapp browser plugin is not loading, but rather a webview. Check all settings and see if the inappbrowser is actually being called.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I suspect of the same, but I don't know where I can find a working version so I can check if it is being called and such. Any guidelines on where to look?

Comment: Take a look at this answer, your idea was right and here's the solution that worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20939897/2637666